# NodeJS_RequestLib - How do I set customHeaders?

Tags: node.js, request

I'm using the request lib [request](https://github.com/request/request) in my project and I need to inform to the API of another company (I can't modify the server) that a transaction was did.
Anyway, to inform to this API I need to use a custom header named `api_key` and when I try to do this, like that:

```
reqOptions = {
    url: 'https://my_url_here.com',
    body: JSON.stringify(transaction),
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'text/xml',
        'charset': 'UTF-8',
        'api_key:': 'my_api_key_here'
    }
};
```

I'm getting the error:

```
error: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_HTTP_TOKEN]: Header name must be a valid HTTP token ["api_key:"]
```

How can I set the custom header?

Comment: you have : in the api_key, remove the : and try  like this --> 'api_key': 'ak_live_a2a8ffae58614a42f6ab67c80a552eb1488e6'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check [Custom HTTP Headers](https://github.com/request/request#custom-http-headers).

Your header have `:`

try use `api_key`.

Answer (score 0):

Try change:

```
'api_key:': 'ak_live_a2a8ffae58614a42f6ab67c80a552eb1488e6'
```

to:

```
'api_key': 'ak_live_a2a8ffae58614a42f6ab67c80a552eb1488e6'
```